# High current voltage reference from a small current constant reference and regulator

Tags: noise, high-current, voltage-reference, voltage-source

Say I need a high current voltage reference. A very accurate and low noise part is available, but can only supply 10mA and happens to be expensive. So multiples of this part cannot be used. What if we were to parallelize it with a voltage source, only separated by a low voltage drop diode.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDaU8W.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Basically, most current is supplied by the the voltage source and the voltage reference just "tops it off". To prevent over-voltage, we set the voltage source very, very slightly below the needed voltage, whether the diode is used or not.

How do I make sure most of the current is drawn from the voltage source (V_REG), instead of the voltage reference component? Do you guys see any other problems that might arise here?

Comment: Your idea of supplying part of the voltage from another source is the wrong way round: if the current required by the load is stable you could supply part of the *current* from a current source. Your voltage reference would supply the remaining current (if it is in the range 0..100mA).

Answer (score 2):

Sorry but this isn't going to work! The 6V source will attempt to supply all of the current to the load. If the load is too great for the 6V source then (usually) its voltage will fall. If it falls to 5.6V then the other regulator V_REG will start to supply current to the load, but only at 5.6V, so you have lost all of the "good" regulation you were hoping for.

Answer (score 2):

In a comment on one of the answers, you say *"I need an absolutely clean reference down to the nanovolt, if possible. Like having a voltage reference battery."* ... and yet you came up with a bone-headed idea like this?

There are so many things wrong here, it's hard to know where to begin. For one thing, you *never draw any current from a reference battery* — you use it to calibrate a secondary (transfer) standard in an arrangement (the original use of the term "potentiometer") that draws zero current when balanced.

Secondly, you seem to be conflating the concepts of accuracy and noise. "Down to the nanovolt" when talking about a 6V source could mean either 0.166 ppb accuracy, or it could mean a noise level of -196 dB. Both are extremely difficult to achieve, so you need to be a lot more clear about what your actual requirements are.

You haven't told us what this "golden reference" that you found actually is, but I'd be very surprised if it meets your "nanovolt" requirement even within its current capacity. You also need to explain why you need so much current.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answer noted, the circuit won't work. Even if it did, you will be ruining your accuracy, as the diode will cause at least a \$60mV\$ drop.

How about simply using an op-amp to buffer the reference voltage? The op-amp then provides essentially all the current from its input voltage (which should of course be somewhat higher than the reference), and with the right part this is certainly more accurate than the circuit you propose. For example [this](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/CD00045727.pdf) might work (that's just what came up first within the requirements, I'm by no means suggesting that it's necessarily the optimal part for this).

Comment: I want it to be free of voltage and current input offsets. True, I could just offset the voltage reference to the input of your op-amp. But there's still the issue of non-linearities, noise, etc... I need an absolutely clean reference down to the nanovolt, if possible. Like having a voltage reference battery.

Comment: Well, in some sense op-amps, or more precisely buffers, are by definition the solution to the problem "I have a voltage, I need to supply the same voltage with a higher current", so generically one would expect the solution to be around the same lines. How about [this](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmv641.pdf), the noise is on the level of \$nV/\sqrt{\mathrm{Hz}}\$ and offset current \$\mu A\$?

Comment: If I may ask, for what do you need a voltage that is so precisely constant?

Comment: How accurate is your 'very accurate' part? I'd be willing to bet that its errors would dominate those caused by a reasonable op-amp's offsets and biasses. And then you can obtain op-amps that are much better than 'reasonable'.

Comment: I updated my answer in accordance with the 100mA requirement you're implicitly stating in the circuit diagram in the original post.

Comment: @Timo LMV641 is not the best one. Check LT1037

Comment: @ilkhd it doesn't look like the LT1037 could supply the 100mA the OP wants, look at the voltage swing figure in the datasheet, at \$100\Omega\$ load it's already down to 3 volts, and 100mA from a 6 volt source corresponds to a resistive load of only \$60\Omega\$.

Comment: @Timo LMV641 has max current 22ma, so won't work without a buffer either.

Comment: @ilkhd true! I just looked it up on Digikey, with the requirement that output current > 100mA, but the datasheet indeed says differently.

Comment: @Timo I am afraid either OP will have to resort to use some very expensive products or use a precision opamp and a transistor and lose precision/noise performance.

Comment: @ilkhd I changed the suggestion, a somewhat worse offset performance but provides the required output.